# Which device spec determines the space Views have

Tags: android, view, android-view

Forgive me if this is a stupid question, I am a beginner.

Suppose I have two devices, Device A is smaller than Device B, both physically and in terms of pixel density.

On Device A, one of my text views does not have enough space and part of its contents get cut off (horizontally). On device B the full content is displayed.

Which aspect of the device sizes primarily cause this discrepancy? Is it the physical size of the screen, or the pixel density? Or something else?

Edit:

My xml looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginHorizontal="9dp"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
      <company.app.common.Button
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/play_store_button_icon"
        android:text="@string/play_now"
      />

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
      >
        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/extra_reward"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
          android:maxLines="1"
          android:textAppearance="@style/BoldText"
          android:textColor="@color/gx_dar_blue"
          android:textSize="18sp"
        />

        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/reward"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
          android:maxLines="1"
          android:textAppearance="@style/BoldText"
          android:textSize="18sp"
        />

        <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
          android:text="@string/reward_rate"
          android:textAppearance="@style/RegularTextPrimary"
          android:textSize="11sp"
        />
      </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Basically, the problem device has a physical size of 5.5" and a pixel density of 443ppi. Part of "@id/reward" gets cut out of the screen, e.g. a number like 4868 would display as 486. I am aware of various methods of **how** to fix the problem, but my question is more conceptual, i.e. what is the critical device property that determines whether the text fits of not.

Comment: We cannot really answer that without a [mcve]. Probably it is physical size, but it could be tied to screen density or font scale.

Comment: You'd get better help if you post the code of your layout and pictures of what it looks like on the bad device.  But there are a LOT of factors.  The size of the screen in pixels, and the logical density (NOT the physical density) are the two main ones.  The logical density is how many pixels per inch the OS thinks there are.  This is <= the physical density.  Some phones purposely have the OS pretend it's less dense than it is, causing everything to draw bigger.

Comment: ALso for text is the scale factor in sp-  do the two devices use the same size of base text, or is one set for a smaller base size?

Comment: Hey @CommonsWare, thanks for the comment. I have added all the code that I can identify as being relevant, hope that clarifies.

Comment: Hey @GabeSechan thanks for the comment. I've added some details about the layout and the device, hope that's acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

So the way Android lays out elements is that the onMeasure() function of the root view of the hierarchy is called.  It returns a measurespec of it's size.  It's responsible for measuring all of it's children as well and calculating it's size off of that.  This will give sizes (either max size or exact size in each direction) for each element.  Then the root element will have onLayout called, passing in it's position, width, and height relative to it's parent.  It is then responsible for deciding where to put each of it's children and calling layout() on each of them in turn passing in their own boundaries.

So assuming that this is your entire hierarchy-  the top linear layout would be given the screen as its width and an unlimited height to work in, to match it's requested match_parent and wrap_content.  Then the linear layout would decide where to layout it's children relative to itself, taking into account padding, margin, etc.

My guess is that this isn't the full hierarchy though.  Since a LinearLayout tends to layout its children in order, my guess is that it just ran out of space-  that the space given to it after subtracting the play button wasn't enough.  And the reason for that to be different between devices could be density, different text size options, different system default fonts, etc.  Lots of variables there.